# How to add percentage column in views

Tags: views

I use [Views Aggregator Plus](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_aggregator) to calculate sum of a column.

----------------------
Item         Data
----------------------
A              20 
B              30
C              50
----------------------
                100
----------------------

Then I want to add additional column for percentage.

-----------------------------------------
Item         Data         Percentage 
-----------------------------------------
A              20 
B              30
C              50
-----------------------------------------
                100
----------------------

I know Global:Math expression. But I don't know how to get the sum, the sum field is not available. Only [value], [value_1] and [value_2] available for A, B and C respectively.

Is there a way to add a percentage column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now this problem has been solved, after [VAP](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_aggregator) add percentage function
http://cgit.drupalcode.org/views_aggregator/commit/?id=2539ac5

Now I can add additional column calculating the percentage (as an example below):
[image]

Comment: I enabled the Views Aggregator Plus More Functions module, but I don't see new functions in Group Agregation column. I created the Count without problem, but I can't find where is the percentage function (Cleared Cache and executed cron several times, even I tried from other browser). Can you bring me the light?

Comment: I think you also need to enable "Views Aggregator Plus More Functions"

Answer (score 1):

You could use preprocess functions and templates for that. Just add an extra field in your view and preprocess the value inside `template_preprocess_views()`.

Add your logic, for example:

```
function template_preprocess_views(&$variables) {
    $variables['percentage'] = $some_value % 100 . '%';
}
```

Then you can use the `$percentage` in your template which will contain your preprocessed value.
I'm just going through this very quick. If something is not clear, please ask and I'll go in further detail on how to tackle this with preprocessors and templates.

Comment: I have added an extra field (Global: Custom text). I don't have any idea where and how I have to write the function. Is it a new module, I have to create a new module?

Comment: Hello Michiel, could you please explain in a more detail. How to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can install [views_php](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_php) module, This module adds a *PHP* field to the view and There are some tokens available. You can use the current row values to calculate percentage.

Comment: Using PHP in views is very risky since it simply process user input... I would not recommend using this if you don't know the content managers...

Comment: @Michiel calculating a simple percentage wont expose the site to any risk. The PHP by itself is not risky, the important thing is how much the codes are sensitive and what information are available through them

Comment: 100% agreed, but generally taken, it's not an optimal solution. I've had some bad experience with a (legacy) project using PHP inside Views. It's an open exposure for someone with thoroughly knowledge. But I'm sure I'm overthinking this for something simple like calculating a percentage. I'ld go for preprocessors.

Comment: May be it loses a tiny portion of  security for the sake of being straightforward, But in such case I myself prefer to use views_php.

Comment: Yes I have Global:PHP now.  I don't know how to calculate percentage. What would be the value code and output code.

Comment: You only need to use the output code. Use the *Devel* module to `kpr` the available tokens ($results)